# How to modify Settings.Designer.cs at build time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build, settings.settings

I have a C# class library project with some settings in `Settings.settings`.  I need to be able to change these settings at build time based on the configuration (Debug, Release, etc.).

It's fairly straightforward to add a pre-build event to copy `Settings.<configuration>.settings` to `Settings.settings`, but as it turns out - this doesn't help!  The settings are taken from `Settings.Designer.cs` which is generated from `Settings.settings` as soon as you save your changes (i.e. at code edit time).

Is there a way to regenerate `Settings.Designer.cs` from `Settings.settings` at compile time?  Or is this the wrong way to go about modifying configuration settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Settings.Designer.cs is generated by the IDE, not MSBuild.  So, no, changing that file at compile time won't have any effect.  You didn't document your question well enough to offer the best alternative, but it sure sounds like using a setting wasn't the correct choice.

Comment: Yes I wasn't clear.  It was a WCF services class library and the service class needed to know the database connection string.  I was using a settings file within this project, but this was completely wrong.  What I did in the end was put the connection string in the web.config of the hosting web app.